# How can I save multi-select value into database

Tags: reactjs, database, function, save, multi-select

I need to save the datas (countries) into database using reactjs and laravel as backend. My laravel is OK but I can't save these options as an array. Here are my function:

```
function SelectTransLanguage() {
        const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});
        const options = [
            { value: "AF", label: "Afghanistan" },
            { value: "AL", label: "Albania" },
            { value: "DZ", label: "Algeria" },
            { value: "AS", label: "American Samoa" },
            { value: "AD", label: "Andorra" },
            { value: "AO", label: "Angola" },
            { value: "AI", label: "Anguilla" },
            // More options
        ];
        const handleChangeOption = () => {
            return setSelectedOption;
        }
        useEffect(() => {
            if (selectedOption.value) {
                console.log(selectedOption)
                setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, translate_list: selectedOption.value })
            }
        }, [selectedOption])

        {console.log(selectedOption)}
        return (
            <Select className={`col-12 o-languages`}
                isMulti    
                onChange={handleChangeOption()}
                options={options} />
        )
    }
```

I tried to save options to laravel (array) but it's not working. What should I do? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ngonNgu state is an object. You can try:

```
 const [ngonNgu, setNgonNgu] = useState([])
 useEffect(() => {
       if (selectedOption.value) {
           console.log(selectedOption)
           setNgonNgu([ ...ngonNgu, translate_list: selectedOption.value ])
       }
 }, [selectedOption])
```